# How do I customize <select> on css?

Tags: html, css

So i am trying to customize a full dropbox (Country Selector) instead of the regular look, I want to add a diferent design to it.

**Regular design**

[[image: Regular Design with a few adjusts on color[1]]

**The Design I want**

[image: The Design I want]

The first image is the default version with color adjustments, its the version that is working on the website, I want to make the design look like the 2nd picture i've uploaded.

The second version is what I got on photoshop, how i do customize my `<select>` to the 2nd picture? here is the code i got on css, I tried to use ::webkit and it didn't work.

**CSS**

```
.paistofill option {
    background-color:#a5e4c9;
    font-weight: normal;
    white-space: pre;
    min-height: 0.0em;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.paistofill select{
    background-color: white;
    color:#a5e4c9;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

The select customization has no effect on the element, what do I need to do?

Comment: You can't. You need to make a replacement with divs, or using plugins like jQueryChosen or Select2, that allows you to stylize them.

Comment: ^ What he said. I was just writing it as an answer while you commented this.

Comment: Could you share the link to your site? It can be useful to help you

Comment: Do i have to download jQueryChosen or can I just import? or call it like bootstrap?

Comment: @jpuriol i can't because it only works on private network for now, i'm not really in charge of that part

Comment: @AndreFIlipe take a look here: https://github.com/select2/select2#usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to use a plugin (or make it yourself) like https://select2.github.io/. You can't really customise the dropdown of the select reliably in every browser. These plugins usually replace and make div elements of the select (and the dropdown) which acts like the normal select. Then you can easily modify these elements with css.

Comment: What is the diference between Chosen and Select2? I also saw the link you added on the comments.

Comment: The difference is just between features of the plugin. I personally have used both but select2 most of the time. You can read some differences in here: https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-select-box-components-chosen-vs-select2/

Comment: I prefer chosen ,better and versatile.

Comment: Yeah, it's just opinion based I would say. Which ever works on normal websites and if some advanced stuff is needed then it should be evaluated which one to use :)